# Run a script at shutdown on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, script, shutdown

I'm trying to run a script right before my Pi shuts down.
OS: Raspbian Stretch

Here is what I did so fare:

1. put my script (name: sendir) in /etc/init.d/
2. created a symbolic link to it in /etc/rc6.d with the name K99sendir

The script is executable and if I run it inside /etc/rc6.d via ./K99sendir it works but it does not work when I actually shutdown the system.

This is what the script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

irsend SEND_ONCE ph_remote KEY_POWER
```

Does anybody have an idea what's missing?

Comment: Just as a side note, `rc6` is for reboot, `rc0` is for shutdown. Not that I expect it to work if you replace 6 with 0.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `systemd`, just put your script to `/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/` as described [here](https://opensource.com/life/16/11/running-commands-shutdown-linux) and [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-halt.service.html).

EDIT:
If it's not working try this one:

Create a systemd service: `/etc/systemd/system/yourSript.service` with following lines:

```
[Unit]
Description=yourScript

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/yourScript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Move your Script to `/usr/local/bin/yourScript`.

And enable the service

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo systemctl enable yourScript.service --now`.

Comment: Actually I tried this method before trying so use the run levels. But for me it also didn't work with the systemd method. Do I really only have to copy the script in this directory or do I have to adjust the script?

Comment: Nice idea :-) But for starting this unit you do not need any dependency. It can start as soon as possible. I think you could omit `RequiresMountsFor=/`. And I won't place it in `/lib/systemd/system/`. Better to use `/etc/systemd/system/`.

Comment: @Ingo You're right, I deleted it.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I created the service according to your description, but after enabling it, I got the following error: `Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable sendir
update-rc.d: error: sendir Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.`

Comment: @apfelcast It works at my raspberry. Could you post the output of `systemctl cat yourScript.service`

Comment: @jake here you go: `# /etc/systemd/system/sendir.service
[Unit]
Description=sendir

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/sendir

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target`

Comment: @apfelcast Looks good. I don't know whats wrong there. When I take your service file it works...

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your script isn't working is that apparently, starting with Jessie, Debian [breaks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347686/106927) compatibility with System V scripts. They still seem to work correctly on startup (their most important use case), but no longer do on shutdown.

You'll have to get used to `systemd`.