# Can't enable service with systemd

Tags: raspbian, systemd

I have created the service `sendir.service` and put it in `/etc/systemd/system`

This is what the service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=sendir

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/sendir

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And this is the script for the service `/usr/local/bin/sendir`:

```
#!/bin/bash

irsend SEND_ONCE ph_remote KEY_POWER
```

When I try to enable the service via `sudo systemctl enable sendir.service --now` I'm getting this error message

```
Synchronizing state of sendir.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable sendir
update-rc.d: error: sendir Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now got the service running by changing the service it self and adding `Before=shutdown.target` to it.

The `sendir.service` now looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description= sending
Before=shutdown.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/sendir
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I could enable the service without any problems now and it also sends the ir signal like is should.

Answer (score 1):

The system is trying to keep the `systemd` System and Service Manager insync with the legacy SYSV (UNIX System V and BSD System and Service Manager).

`systemd` is controlled using `systemctl`, while `SYSV` is controlled using the `service` command.

I believe that [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/909523/default-start-contains-no-runlevels-aborting?answertab=active) is the fix for your problem.  The only thing different about your situation is that your custom script runs at service stop instead of service start.

Try adding the following to your `/usr/bin/local/sendir` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          sendir
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Execute sendir at service termination ...
### END INIT INFO
```

Comment: The file already points at the service file: `ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/sendir`. It should be executed at every shutdown as you can see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89732/run-a-script-at-shutdown-on-raspbian/89737#89737).

Comment: @jake Ah, I didn't catch that ... you're saying that `/usr/local/bin/sendir` is the Bash script he shows.  Perhaps then the `sendir` file just needs to include the `BEGIN INIT INFO`.  I'll edit the question to show the name of the Bash script.

Comment: Maybe he could put his one-liner directly into the service file.  Like `ExecStop=/bin/bash irsend SEND_ONCE ph_remote KEY_POWER`. What do you think?

Comment: I have now tried both methods. I have added the `BEGIN INIT INFO` to the script and also put the command like @jake mentioned directly in the service. Bot I got the exact same error message again, when I try to enable the service. Can it be that somethings is wrong with the service file itself?

Comment: @apfelcast What version of Raspbian are you using? I'm on Stretch version 9 and the enable worked for me.  I need try again this time removing the INIT INFO to see if I can recreate your error.

Comment: @apfelcast I can't get it to fail with your error