# Turn SenseHat leds off at shutdown

Tags: systemd, sense-hat

I am trying to turn off the SenseHat leds when the device reboots/shutsdown etc.
The reason is that the leds stay at their last pattern so I cannot visually tell if the machine has actually shutdown.
(wouldn't it be nice if 'shutdown' meant 'turn-off')

I have tried a lot of variants of the systemd configuration such as
[Run a script at shutdown on Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89732/run-a-script-at-shutdown-on-raspbian)
but nothing actually works.
I have a tiny python program that puts a big X on the display - this works
and a script that calls this - also works.

I dont know how to tell if the service actually fires
Does anybody know when the ability to set these leds actually stops. ie I am not needing the file system which I know gets remounted as part of shutdown etc

the latest contents of /etc/systemd/system/SenseBigX.service are

```
[Unit]
Description=SenseBigX
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/SenseBigX

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thanks in advance
JC